# jQuery/Ajax contact form not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to jQuery. I am trying to submit a contact form, and the display a thank you message for feedback. I had a look at the tutorial at NetTuts+.My form is not being submitted. Here is my code:

jQuery

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.error').hide();
        $("#submitButton").click(function() {
            $('.error').hide();  
            var name = $("input#name").val();  
            if (name == "") {  
                $("label#name_error").show();  
                $("input#name").focus();  
                return false;  
            }  
            var email = $("input#email").val();  
            if (email == "") {  
                $("label#email_error").show();  
                $("input#email").focus();  
                return false;  
            }  
            var companyName = $("#usermessage").val();  
            if (companyName == "") {  
                $("label#message_error").show();  
                $("input#usermessage").focus();  
                return false;  
            } 
            var subject=$("#subject option:selected").text();
            var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + companyName;  
            //alert (dataString);return false;  
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "mailer.php",  
                data: dataString,  
                success: function() {  
                    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
                    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")  
                        .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")  
                        .hide()  
                        .fadeIn(1500, function() {  
                            $('#message').append("Thank you");  
                        });  
                }  
            });  
            return false; 
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $mailTo = 'varma.anirudh12@gmail.com';
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
    $mailFrom = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $subjectNumber = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']);
    $message_text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['msg']);
    switch ($subjectNumber)
    {
        case 0:
            $subject='Sales';
            break;
        case 1:
            $subject='Careers';
            break;
        case 2:
            $subject='Other';
            break;
    }
    $dataString=htmlspecialchars($_POST['dataString']);
    //$message =  'From: '.$name.'; Email: '.$mailFrom.' ; Message: '.$message_text;

    $sendcon=mail($mailTo, $subject, $message);
    if ( isset($_GET["ajax"]) ) {
        echo $sendcon ? "success" : "error";
    } else {

}

?>
```

The issue is that on pressing the submit button, nothing happens. There are no errors on the javascript console.
I think that my php is not correct and is not listening to the Ajax data, as the error log of apache  says `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: dataString`.

where am i going wrong?
thanks

**EDIT: I Am running this on localhost on an ubuntu machine, I have set up the mail server and tested it with a test email**

Comment: If you go into Chrome -> Network and click "Submit", you should see and HTTP request. Does the form look like it's passing the data to the server correctly?

Comment: post your HTML form code

Comment: dataString is not present in the url you set up as data in your ajax call.

Comment: @EmCo [Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/) in STEP 4 it does not say anything regarding datastring

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following:

```
$.post("mailer.php", { name: "John", email: "jsmith@xyz.com" } );
```

Comment: Hey...thanks for the link...
But I ended up using the json method from this [link](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2012/03/05/whats-the-best-jquery-method-for-retrieving-ajax-data/)

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if we could see your form code too. I've put together a tutorial here: http://blog.fraser-hart.co.uk/ajax-contact-form-tutorial/

You can download the files and compare them to what you have come up with. Have a read through and let me know if you've any questions about how anything works and I'll point you in the right direction

Comment: Hey...thanks for the link...
But I ended up using the json method from this [link](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2012/03/05/whats-the-best-jquery-method-for-retrieving-ajax-data/)

Comment: No probs. Let me know if you get stuck with anything

Comment: I am stuck with Ajax [again] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826776/ajax-php-not-working-correctly)