# Ajax-PHP not working correctly

Tags: php, jquery

The AJAX-PHP bug has bit me again.Now here's the problem
I am to send some form data from HTML to PHP using AJAX,(I'm using jQuery for this) and then use that data, play with it in PHP and give some result.
The Ajax call is made successfully, but the issue is that not all data is being sent to PHP that is some data goes missing `if I interpreted it correctly` 
The jQuery/Ajax Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
     var data=$("#Form").serialize();
       console.log(data);
         $.ajax({

        type:'POST',
        url:('php/api.php'),
        data:"datastring="+data,
        success: function(d){           
        console.log("php response "+d);
      }         

       });
   });

 });
```

And the PHP

```
<?php
   $data=$_POST['datastring'];
   echo($data);
?>
```

Now here's the output from the console

```
     first+name=first&last+name=second&some+detail=third&comments=fourth //output from 1st          console.log() statement
  php response first name=first //output from php
```

As you can see from the above statement only the first value is echoed why?
Does it mean it did not recieve the full value from AJAX?

Thanks

Comment: ok first, the last bit of the code, thats not what php printed out... `php response first name=first //output from php` could you only include what the php file included? try removing datastring from ` data:"datastring="+data,` and try it

Comment: Use Firebug to see what's sent over the wire.

Comment: Well then how do I reference it in PHP, I have tried that but I get `Undefined index: data` error

Comment: you got it is't only sending the First Name, but the question is WHY??

Comment: the answers are below, it is sending everything, you are just outputting it incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you assigning it to datastring?

Just add the datastring without the predecessor to it.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'php/api.php',
    data:data,
    success: function(d){           
    console.log("php response "+d);
  }
});
```

Then in your php:

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Edit: fixed the php side. Thanks! unfixed it though!

Comment: Good point, I had initially planned to echo <pre> tags but left it out for simplicity, +1 for the spot!

Comment: if you put the `echo` away, you need to put the `, 1` in `print_r` away as well :)

Comment: I removed the echo though :P

Comment: @francisco.preller Spot on thanks.. will accept it in 3 minutes

Comment: @lazyprogrammer If the answer was helpful, please mark it so others can find it easier in future.

Comment: can please explain why my code was sending only the first value? just out of curiosity

Comment: Yes, because it was looking for an assignment to a variable named 'datastring' which was only for the first value, and was later overriden by the other & symbols on the string

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you, don't put any `()` in the `url` :

```
 $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'php/api.php',
    data:{data : $("#Form").serialize()}, //<---You can put the directly here
    success: function(d){           
       console.log("php response "+d);
    }         
});
```

and in `php` file again remove the `()` from `echo($data);` in use `$_POST['data'];`:

```
<?php
   $data=$_POST['data'];
   echo $data;
?>
```

Try this and see if helps.

Comment: There is never a data variable passed, he should just assign $_POST to $data. Or better yet, skip assigning alltogether :]

Comment: Oh Thanks @francisco.preller just fixed it.